# setting value of attribute using php echo does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried the following code:

```
<input name="first-name" type="text" class="form-control" 
    placeholder=<?php echo (form_error('birth-date') !== '') ? 'Please enter name' : 'Enter name'; ?> >
```

However, the output is only either "Please" or "Enter". It doesn't show the rest of the characters after first space.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HTML attribute values containing whitespace (or always imo) should be enclosed in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the `"`

```
<input name="first-name" type="text" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="<?php echo (form_error('birth-date') !== '') ? 'PLease enter name' : 'Enter name'; ?>">
```

Comment: thank you! i thought it does not need the " coz it works when i only have one word to echo. that was dumb of me. XD thanks so much!